# Is there a way to color a portion of text in a field of a listview?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, visual-studio-2015

We can make use of `Foreground` property to change the color of a field in a listview, but is there a way to change a portion of the text in the field to a certain color?

For example I want sample text appeared as red color
[image]

Comment: Only if you draw it all yourself:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.drawitem(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can have some html as the text to do it. For example "This is a sample text". You want to display the "sample text" in red. Here is how the text is going to be

```
This is a <span style='color:red'>sample text</span>
```

Comment: It does not work, I have changed the question of what it appears

Comment: I'm assuming you are trying to show this on a web page. If yes, can you share how it appears on the web page. If not, then is it a windows app?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. Yes, it is a windows apps, adding this information to the question :)